# JS validation false, form still submitting

Tags: javascript

I've got a JS problem. My validation seems to be working, checking that the user inputs a valid number which isn't zero, but the form is still submitting. I have seen this question asked many times but I can't find a solution that works for me. Any ideas would be great.

My Javascript

```
function checkNotZero()
{
    var theNumber = document.getElementById("theNumber").value;
    var str = /^\+?[1-9]\d*$/.test(theNumber);
    if ( str == false ) {
        alert('You have not entered a valid number');
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('numberCheck').submit();   
    }
}
```

My HTML

```
<form action="/next.php" method="post" id="numberCheck">
<input type="text" id="theNumber" value="0">
<button id="submitButton" OnClick="checkNotZero();">Add to Basket</button>
</form>
```

Comment: if you comment `document.getElementById('numberCheck').submit();` is there still a submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi for the above requirement of 'validating form' java script validation should be done 
when the form gets submitted. follow the below approach, form will not get submitted 
until and unless the validation is correct.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkNotZero()
{
var theNumber = document.getElementById("theNumber").value;
var str = /^\+?[1-9]\d*$/.test(theNumber);
if ( str == false ) {
alert('in');
alert('You have not entered a valid number');
return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('numberCheck').submit();   
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/next.php" method="post" id="numberCheck"  onsubmit="return       
checkNotZero()">
<input type="text" id="theNumber" value="0">
 <button id="submitButton">Add to Basket</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the only change is `<form action="/next.php" method="post" id="numberCheck"

     onsubmit="return checkNotZero()">`
do not use `onclick` event in submit button.

Answer (score 1):

- Use an `<input type="submit">` for the submit button.
- Validate on the `form`'s submit event rather than some `onclick`. Forms can get submitted in other ways than just clicking a button (for instance, pressing "enter", or procedurally through code).
- Prefer `.addEventListener` to attributes for attaching events to elements. Use `preventDefault()` to prevent form submission.

Comment: Because the `<button>` submits the form by itself even without the `onclick` handler. See [button.type on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#type)

Comment: I don't see anything related in that page, am I not looking good enough?